# update One Recycler view from another RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two Recycler views inside a LinearLayout in a fragment. one horizontal recycler view at the top of fragment and below that a vertical recyclerview. What i want to do is to add items from the vertical Recyclerview to horizontal Recyclerview by long touching the items.each of Recyclerviews has it's own adapter.how can i add/remove items to/from the top RV and refresh the view at the same time?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel in the top RV i show pinned contacts. i save a list of pinned items in sharedPreferences and add items to this list when long touching items in the below RV. when i start my app i load the list into top RV and show pinned items and there is no problem here. but my problem is how to add items to top RV at the same time i long touch the item in the below RV?how to notify the top RV adapter from the below RV adapter?

Comment: when long touch on below RV get that item and put in in preference / top RV and then, just call topRVAdapter.notifyDataSetchanged()

Comment: @DivyeshPatel not clear ?  i think it is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: remove item from below RV and put it in Top RV then call adpater.notifydatasetchanged in both